# Firebase check if user is disabled

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an Android app using Firebase but however I do not know how to check if the user is disabled on sign in so I can show a custom alert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: What do u mean by disabled?

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239979/how-to-check-whether-user-is-disabled-or-not-in-firebase-auth) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that a user account is disabled when signing in, because `getErrorCode()` will return `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` exception with `ERROR_USER_DISABLED`. See the [reference documentation of `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException).

If you want to check before signing in that an account is disabled, that can only be done with the Firebase Admin SDK, because it is a sensitive operation. For example when you [retrieve the user record](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) with the Node.js SDK, the user record contains a [`disabled`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#disabled) property with the value you're looking for. Be careful in how you expose this information to your client-side app though, as it is easy to leak sensitive information if you're not careful.