# Is it a good idea to call Firebase reload() inside OnAuthStateChanged?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it a good idea to call Firebase reload() inside OnAuthStateChanged?  Initially I would call reload() during app initialization, but it's not guaranteed the FirebaseUser object has been loaded yet.  Seems a clean way to do it is call inside OnAuthStateChanged() if the user is not null.  The logic being that the returned user profile would match what's cached and no subsequent calls to OnAuthStateChanged will be issued.  It works - but I'm a bit worried about a run-away loop for reasons that may not be obvious to me.

```
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)
            {
                final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
             
                //call reload here???

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.reload().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                        {
                            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException)
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "INVALID USER EXCEPTION: " + e);
                                Disconnect();
                                SignOut();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not expect `reload()` to do anything significant at all on a newly signed in user.  Since `onAuthStateChanged` indicates that the user has just signed in, the profile information should have just been loaded from the backend service.  Reloading at that point isn't likely to be helpful.

Reloading is intended for times when a user has been signed in for a while, and your code is trying to check if something changed with its profile since it was last signed in.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong - but that's not what I'm seeing.  If I disable the account and re-start the app onAuthStateChanged returns the profile that was already signed in and cached.  It is supposed to return with NULL if the account is disabled

Comment: This is also described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239979/how-to-check-whether-user-is-disabled-or-not-in-firebase-auth)

Comment: I just want check if the user account is still valid in the early boot part of the app - and thought onAuthStateChanged might actually be a good place for it...

Comment: The Firebase Auth SDK would not allow a user to sign in at all if their account wasn't valid.

Comment: I don't automatically sign users out - they stay signed in.  Am I supposed to?  When the app is restarted FirebaseAuth still has the cached user profile and I've verified that it generates onAuthStateChanged with the cached data even if that account is disabled/deleted.  So either I wait an hour for the token to expire (I assume that would work but not sure) or force reload().  Can't call reload() in activity cycle callbacks because there is no guarantee the user profile has been loaded - so I either do it from a timer or call in onStateAuthChanged()

Comment: And it works like a charm - but back to the question, is that a good idea?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling reload unless you know you have a specific reason to.  Don't do it "defensively".  Have a specific reason.

Comment: The specific reason is to prevent disabled account from using the app.  But I think I see now where I'm confused.  After the token expires firebase must reload the profile automatically whether or not the user is manually signed out or if the app is running or not.  So at some point if the app is restarted onAuthStateChanged must get a null, right?  Since the FirebaseUser object returned at that point is null - is there a way to check if the reason specifically was a deleted/disabled account?

Comment: The user is not given a reason why their account was disabled.